# where is mouse cursor movement acceleration and scroll wheel acceleration implemented in MacOSX

Tags: macos, events, mouseevent, iokit

Where is mouse cursor movement acceleration and scroll wheel acceleration implemented in MacOSX?

On the API level, [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics) / [Quartz Event Services](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/quartz_event_services) provides the [CGEvent](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgevent) type.

On the application side, there are many relevant and interesting comments at [this Chrome change review](https://codereview.chromium.org/42607), and extracted from there [this comment](https://gist.github.com/svoisen/5215826):

```
// Of Mice and Men
// ---------------
//
// There are three types of scroll data available on a scroll wheel CGEvent.
// Apple's documentation ([1]) is rather vague in their differences, and not
// terribly helpful in deciding which to use. This is what's really going on.
//
// First, these events behave very differently depending on whether a standard
// wheel mouse is used (one that scrolls in discrete units) or a
// trackpad/Mighty Mouse is used (which both provide continuous scrolling).
// You must check to see which was used for the event by testing the
// kCGScrollWheelEventIsContinuous field.
//
// Second, these events refer to "axes". Axis 1 is the y-axis, and axis 2 is
// the x-axis.
//
// Third, there is a concept of mouse acceleration. Scrolling the same amount
// of physical distance will give you different results logically depending on
// whether you scrolled a little at a time or in one continuous motion. Some
// fields account for this while others do not.
//
// Fourth, for trackpads there is a concept of chunkiness. When scrolling
// continuously, events can be delivered in chunks. That is to say, lots of
// scroll events with delta 0 will be delivered, and every so often an event
// with a non-zero delta will be delivered, containing the accumulated deltas
// from all the intermediate moves. [2]
//
// For notchy wheel mice (kCGScrollWheelEventIsContinuous == 0)
// ------------------------------------------------------------
//
// kCGScrollWheelEventDeltaAxis*
//   This is the rawest of raw events. For each mouse notch you get a value of
//   +1/-1. This does not take acceleration into account and thus is less
//   useful for building UIs.
//
// kCGScrollWheelEventPointDeltaAxis*
//   This is smarter. In general, for each mouse notch you get a value of
//   +1/-1, but this _does_ take acceleration into account, so you will get
//   larger values on longer scrolls. This field would be ideal for building
//   UIs except for one nasty bug: when the shift key is pressed, this set of
//   fields fails to move the value into the axis2 field (the other two types
//   of data do). This wouldn't be so bad except for the fact that while the
//   number of axes is used in the creation of a CGScrollWheelEvent, there is
//   no way to get that information out of the event once created.
//
// kCGScrollWheelEventFixedPtDeltaAxis*
//   This is a fixed value, and for each mouse notch you get a value of
//   +0.1/-0.1 (but, like above, scaled appropriately for acceleration). This
//   value takes acceleration into account, and in fact is identical to the
//   results you get from -[NSEvent delta*]. (That is, if you linked on Tiger
//   or greater; see [2] for details.)
//
// A note about continuous devices
// -------------------------------
//
// There are two devices that provide continuous scrolling events (trackpads
// and Mighty Mouses) and they behave rather differently. The Mighty Mouse
// behaves a lot like a regular mouse. There is no chunking, and the
// FixedPtDelta values are the PointDelta values multiplied by 0.1. With the
// trackpad, though, there is chunking. While the FixedPtDelta values are
// reasonable (they occur about every fifth event but have values five times
// larger than usual) the Delta values are unreasonable. They don't appear to
// accumulate properly.
//
// For continuous devices (kCGScrollWheelEventIsContinuous != 0)
// -------------------------------------------------------------
//
// kCGScrollWheelEventDeltaAxis*
//   This provides values with no acceleration. With a trackpad, these values
//   are chunked but each non-zero value does not appear to be cumulative.
//   This seems to be a bug.
//
// kCGScrollWheelEventPointDeltaAxis*
//   This provides values with acceleration. With a trackpad, these values are
//   not chunked and are highly accurate.
//
// kCGScrollWheelEventFixedPtDeltaAxis*
//   This provides values with acceleration. With a trackpad, these values are
//   chunked but unlike Delta events are properly cumulative.
//
// Summary
// -------
//
// In general the best approach to take is: determine if the event is
// continuous. If it is not, then use the FixedPtDelta events (or just stick
// with Cocoa events). They provide both acceleration and proper horizontal
// scrolling. If the event is continuous, then doing pixel scrolling with the
// PointDelta is the way to go. In general, avoid the Delta events. They're
// the oldest (dating back to 10.4, before CGEvents were public) but they lack
// acceleration and precision, making them useful only in specific edge cases.
//
// References
// ----------
//
// [1] <http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html>
// [2] <http://developer.apple.com/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html>
//     Scroll to the section headed "NSScrollWheel events".
//
// P.S. The "smooth scrolling" option in the system preferences is utterly
// unrelated to any of this.
```

On the kernel level, [I/O Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the basic driver interface, and I guess the mouse is of the HID (Human Interface Devices) family (IOHIDFamily). The [XNU kernel source can be seen here](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu) but I'm not sure if that is complete because I don't find a single match when I search for IOHIDFamily. The code might be [here at IOHIDFamily](https://github.com/aosm/IOHIDFamily/tree/master/IOHIDFamily). Actually I found in [IOHIPointing.cpp](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/IOHIDFamily/blob/c56e1c1b2469d9956a585cc2518c8f0c51b5809d/IOHIDSystem/IOHIPointing.cpp#L25) the comment:

```
/*
 * 17 July  1998    sdouglas    Initial creation
 * 01 April     2002    ryepez      added support for scroll acceleration
 */
```

And from the code, it looks like it's implemented there. Can someone confirm?
Also see [here](https://github.com/practicalswift/osx/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=kIOHIDScrollAccelerationKey&type=).

How does the logic in IOHIPointing get finally to the CGEvent? Is that all part of Core Graphics / Quartz? What is in between? Are that some kind of Mach events? Is there any good overview about the generic architecture?

Note that I was wondering about this question because of an ongoing discussion where to implement [mouse scroll wheel acceleration in Linux / Xorg / libinput here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29905).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good, question - and a big one at that. I should note that I don't have full information - as you've discovered, a lot of this is closed source. As far as I've been able to tell, these are the important points:

- <s>The mouse settings (tracking speed, scrolling speed, etc.) you see in System Preferences for a generic, non-Apple mouse are all handled inside WindowServer - where the `CGEvent`s originate. There is some massaging of HID reports going on in `IOHIDPointing` etc. but from what I've seen this is mostly for maintaining compatibility with quirky devices.</s>
- **Update:** (see discussion in comments) It looks like WindowServer probably passes the acceleration parameters down to the kernel driver by setting properties on its IORegistry entry.
- I believe the momentum scrolling for Apple touch devices (trackpads, magic mouse) may actually at least partially be implemented in their respective closed source kernel drivers, such as `AppleMultitouchTrackpadHIDEventDriver`.
- The source code for the lower level userspace side of the HID stack is available in the [IOKitUser](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/) source bundle. This includes the `IOHIDManager` and so on.
- The journey from device to CGEvent is roughly: Device -> `IOHIDDevice` -> `IOHIDInterface` -> `IOHIDEventDriver` -> [`IOHIDevice`] -> `IOHIDSystem` -> `IOHIDUserClient` -> IOKit kernel-user communications mechanism (uses Mach Ports internally) -> HID parts of IOKitUser -> WindowServer (Core Graphics).
- You can bypass this path from a userspace process by directly connecting to an `IOHIDDevice` via a `IOHIDLibUserClient`.

The IOKitUser source might answer some of your questions in more detail. Or if you're trying to do something specific, open a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I looked a bit through the IOKitUser code ([here](https://github.com/opensource-apple/IOKitUser/)) and I just found some `IOHIDSetScrollAcceleration`/`IOHIDSetMouseAcceleration` and related functions ([see also](https://github.com/practicalswift/osx/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=kIOHIDScrollAccelerationKey&type=)), so I guess IOKitUser does not have any logic for this but IOHIPointing does. Maybe the multitouch-driver and the WindowServer do as well.

Comment: @Albert interesting, looks like those functions call down to setting properties on the IO Registry object, so yes, looks like it happens in-kernel after all.